After installing react-native-fast-openpgp for End-to-End Encryption, iOS build failed. How can I fix this?
The problem arises after installing the react-native-fast-openpgp package for implementing End-to-End Encryption in a React Native project. Upon attempting to build the iOS version of the project, the build fails.
After installing and integrating the react-native-fast-openpgp package into my React Native project to enable End-to-End Encryption, I anticipated a successful build of the iOS version without any errors. However, upon attempting the build, I encountered issues. I now require guidance on the post-installation configuration steps specifically tailored for iOS.
